# Encryption in unity c#

Tags: c#, encryption, unity-game-engine

I have an encrypt and decrypt script that work perfectly fine but my question is, how secure is it really? I used some of the script from another source and added the salt myself. I'm not using the script for anything that requires high security, just encryption for a single player save game data currently.

Any advice or suggestions would also be appreciated since I'm new to encryption.

Thanks in advance!

```
    using System;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

public static class Crypto
{
    private const string saltIndiatior = "MySaltIndacationString"
    private const int startSaltLength = 32;
    private const int endSaltLength = 32;

    public static string RandomString(int length)
    {
        var chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!@#$%^&*<>+-=_";
        var stringChars = new char[length];
        var random = new System.Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < stringChars.Length; i++)
        {
            stringChars[i] = chars[random.Next(chars.Length)];
        }

        return new String(stringChars);
    }
    private static string GetSalt(int max)
    {
        byte[] salt = new byte[max];
        RNGCryptoServiceProvider.Create().GetNonZeroBytes(salt);
        return UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(salt);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Encrypts a message
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="toEncrypt">plain text to encrypt</param>
    /// <param name="key">Length must be 32</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string Encrypt(string toEncrypt, string key)
    {
        string startSalt = RandomString(startSaltLength);
        string salt = GetSalt(endSaltLength);
        byte[] keyArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
        // 256-AES key
        byte[] toEncryptArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(startSalt + saltIndiatior + "{" + salt.Length + "}" + toEncrypt + salt);
        RijndaelManaged rDel = new RijndaelManaged();
        rDel.Key = keyArray;
        rDel.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        rDel.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        // better lang support
        ICryptoTransform cTransform = rDel.CreateEncryptor();
        byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(toEncryptArray, 0, toEncryptArray.Length);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(resultArray, 0, resultArray.Length);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Decrypts a message
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="toDecrypt">encrypt</param>
    /// <param name="key"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string Decrypt(string toDecrypt, string key)
    {
        Debug.Log("Decrypting::" + toDecrypt);
        byte[] keyArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
        // AES-256 key
        byte[] toEncryptArray = Convert.FromBase64String(toDecrypt);
        RijndaelManaged rDel = new RijndaelManaged();
        rDel.Key = keyArray;
        rDel.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        rDel.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        // better lang support
        ICryptoTransform cTransform = rDel.CreateDecryptor();
        byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(toEncryptArray, 0, toEncryptArray.Length);
        string decoded = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resultArray);

        Debug.Log("0(decoded)::" + decoded);
        //Remove 32 char long startSalt
        decoded = decoded.Remove(0, startSaltLength);

        if (decoded.StartsWith(saltIndiatior))
        {
            string saltSize = decoded.Substring(0, 1 + decoded.IndexOf("}"));
            Debug.Log("1 (salt Indicator):: " + saltSize);
            int saltLength = int.Parse(saltSize.Replace(saltIndiatior, "").Replace("{", "").Replace("}", ""));
            Debug.Log("2(saltLength):: " + saltLength);
            Debug.Log("3(salt)::" + decoded.Substring(decoded.Length - saltLength, saltLength));
            decoded = decoded.Remove(0, saltSize.Length);
            if (saltLength > 0)
            {
                decoded = decoded.Remove(decoded.Length - saltLength, saltLength);
            }
            Debug.Log("Finished:: " + decoded);
            return decoded;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("ERROR: could not decrypt properly");
            return decoded;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure if someone wants to cheat, they would just decompile your game (and then see your encryption), or use some cheat engine to add millions of gold, then save game security doesn't really matter much.. But of course its better than nothing, so cannot use text editor to add items..

Comment: It uses ECB so not that secure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what kind of game you are working on. If it is a offline game and you are storing the salt on player's computer, it is not that secure. It may be a little difficult to find out at first, but once it is discovered, it equals to not encrypted.

If you don't want players to modify their save data, the most secure way is to host them on your server. However, I suggest that you do not need to concern about save data if it is just a offline game. Let players do whatever they, if the game crash, it is their problem.

Comment: Okay, that makes scene. Thanks : )